# How to put date into drilldown chart title based on drilled point x value (datetime)..?

Tags: charts, highcharts, title, drilldown

My drilldown works fine, yet I can't figure out how to make my drilldown chart title show the drilled point x value (datetime) in the format "Sales of YYYY-MM-DD".

Going back to initial chart title "Sales" (on drillup event) works good.

```
$(function () {    
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false,
        timeZoneOffset: -180
    },
    lang: {
        drillUpText: ' < Back '
    }
});
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: [{
        id: 0,
        minorTickLength: 0,
        labels: {
            y: 15,
            format: '{value:%e %b}',
            zIndex: 0
        },
        tickPixelInterval: 10,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        tickColor: '#e0e0e0',
        pointPadding: 0.05,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        type: 'datetime'
    },{
        id: 1,
        minorTickLength: 0,
        labels: {
            y: 15,
            zIndex: 0
        },
        tickPixelInterval: 2,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        tickColor: '#e0e0e0',
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        type: 'category',
        lineWidth: 0
    }],
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        gridLineColor: '#e0e0e0',
        labels: {
            y: 0,
            x: 0,
            overflow: 'justify',
            enabled: false,
            maxStaggerLines: 0,
            align: 'center'
        },
        title: {
            margin: 0,
            text: null
        },
        gridLineInterpolation: null
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        shared: true,
        xDateFormat: '%e %b',
        valueSuffix: ' Lt',
        borderColor: 'null',
        borderRadius: 10
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            lineColor: '#c0c0c0',
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                fillColor: '#e0e0e0',
                radius: 3,
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#c0c0c0'
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 3,
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        column: {
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: false,
                overflow: 'none',
                y: -10,
                x: 0,
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                padding: 0,
            }
        }
    },
    chart: {
        events: {
            drilldown: function(){
                UpdateTitle('Sales of '+this)
                },
            drillup: function(){
                UpdateTitle('Sales')
            }
        },
        spacingBottom: 20,
        type: 'column',
        borderRadius: 2,
        spacingTop: 0,
        width: 1012,
        marginLeft: 0,
        pacingRight: 0,
        marginBottom: 40,
        marginRight: 0,
        marginTop: 20,
        height: 180,
        spacingLeft: 0
    },
    title: {
        margin: 10,
        y: 15,
        text: 'Sales',
        x: 20,
        align: 'left',
    },
    Exporting: {
        scale: 1,
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false,
        symbolWidth: 12
    },
    series: [ {
        index: 1,
        type: 'column',
        color: '#30bf09',
        name: 'Sales',
        data: [{
            x: 1399410000000,
            y: 16675,
            drilldown: 'day01'
        },{
            x: 1399496400000,
            y: 6906,
            drilldown: 'day02'
        },{
            x: 1399582800000,
            y: 5290,
            drilldown: 'day03'
        },{
            x: 1399669200000,
            y: 764,
            drilldown: 'day04'
        },{
            x: 1399755600000,
            y: 248,
            drilldown: 'day05'
        },{
            x: 1399842000000,
            y: 8585,
            drilldown: 'day06'
        },{
            x: 1399928400000,
            y: 5176,
            drilldown: 'day07'
        },{
            x: 1400014800000,
            y: 10836,
            drilldown: 'day08'
        },{
            x: 1400101200000,
            y: 13217,
            drilldown: 'day09'
        },{
            x: 1400187600000,
            y: 7213,
            drilldown: 'day10'
        },{
            x: 1400274000000,
            y: 711,
            drilldown: 'day11'
        },{
            x: 1400360400000,
            y: 1038,
            drilldown: 'day12'
        },{
            x: 1400446800000,
            y: 6612,
            drilldown: 'day13'
        },{
            x: 1400533200000,
            y: 14496,
            drilldown: 'day14'
        }]
    },{
        index: 0,
        type: 'areaspline',
        color: '#e0e0e0',
        name: 'Planas',
        data: [
            [1399410000000, 2930],
            [1399496400000, 2930],
            [1399582800000, 2930],
            [1399669200000, 0],
            [1399755600000, 0],
            [1399842000000, 2930],
            [1399928400000, 2930],
            [1400014800000, 2930],
            [1400101200000, 2930],
            [1400187600000, 2930],
            [1400274000000, 0],
            [1400360400000, 0],
            [1400446800000, 2930],
            [1400533200000, 2930]
        ]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        activeAxisLabelStyle: {
            textDecoration: 'none',
            fontWeight: 'regular',
            color: '7f7f7f'
        },
        activeDataLabelStyle: {
            textDecoration: 'none',
            fontWeight: 'semi-bold',
            color: '4c4c4c'
        },
        drillUpButton: {
            relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
            position: {
                align: 'right',
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                verticalAlign: 'top'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            id: 'day01',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Presta', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['ESET', 75],
                ['SoftMak', 75],
                ['Google', 750],
                ['Blancco', 0],
                ['Axence', 200],
                ['Kiti', 1500],
                ['...', 0],
                ['...', 0],
                ['Box', 550],
                ['Nuoma', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day02',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftM', 75],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day03',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day04',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day05',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day06',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day07',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day08',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day09',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day10',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day11',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day12',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day13',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75]
            ]
            },{
            id: 'day14',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [ 
                ['ESET', 10000],
                ['OERP', 4000],
                ['Google', 2000],
                ['Export', 600],
                ['SoftMaker', 75],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ],
                [ , ]
            ]}
        ]
    }
})
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
function UpdateTitle(argument1) {
    chart.setTitle({text: argument1})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a drilldown event you have access to clicked point: `e.point`. For example to get timestamp of clicked point use `e.point.x`. Now simply parse that timestamps to required format and it should work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/nJFZN/

```
            drilldown: function (e) {
                UpdateTitle('Sales of ' + e.point.x)
            },
```

Comment: I am quite new to programming and to Highcharts. Would you, please, give me a clue how to make this date in YYYY-MM-DD in the title..?

Comment: Just in case: you can use `Highcharts.dateFormat()`.